# Open CV Error when I am trying to open the webcam

Tags: python, opencv

```
OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-1drr4hl0\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:651:
    error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented.
  Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support.
  If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
  re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

Comment: Did you compile it yourself, or did you install it with pip? What OS are you on?

Comment: please include the code you ran to produce this error